# Vuetify data table add additional column header with icon/button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm creating custom table with Vuetify and I need to add one additional column with an icon button, which would allow me to toggle showing headers (3 dots toggle menu with headers).

[image: Table headers toggle]

Right now I'm looping over all headers:

```
<template v-for="header in $attrs.headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]>
...
</template>
```

I tried to add one more slot with header but it creates it below main row.

```
<template v-slot:header>
  <v-btn>
  //icon
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

Is there a way to add one more static header with just a button?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to override the whole `v-slot:header`.

The main idea is:

1. Add a surrogate "actions" column
2. Inject **active** prop into all of your columns
3. Use computed headers filtered by **active** prop instead of data headers

A little messy but working solution:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="activeHeaders"
  :items="desserts"
  :items-per-page="5"
>
  <template #header.actions="props">
    <v-menu
      v-model="menu"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      offset-y
      :transition="false"
    >
    <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>

    <v-card>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item v-for="item in headers" :key="item.value" v-if="item.value !== 'actions'">
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="item.active"
            />
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content style="cursor: default">
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
...
data () {
  return {
    menu: false,
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'start',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name',
        active: true,
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', active: true, },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat', active: true, },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs', active: true, },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein', active: true, },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron', active: true, },
      { text: '', value: 'actions', active: true, sortable: false, width: '20px', class: 'px-0'}
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
},
computed: {
  activeHeaders() {
    return this.headers.filter(header => header.active)
  }
}
```

You may test this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/ExwoZdL).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gives me some idea. There are still few things to do but at least I know where to go from here.